# Disconnect VPN Using the Command Line

Tags: windows-vista, command-line, vpn, connection

I make VPN connections using Vista's Connection Manager, and would like to disconnect the VPN connection from the command line so I can create a shortcut command called `vpn.disconnect` in [Promptu Launcher](http://www.promptulauncher.com).

How can I disconnect the VPN connection via the command line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check out Rasdial (part of Windows):

USAGE:

```
    rasdial entryname [username [password|*]] [/DOMAIN:domain]
            [/PHONE:phonenumber] [/CALLBACK:callbacknumber]
            [/PHONEBOOK:phonebookfile] [/PREFIXSUFFIX]

    rasdial [entryname] /DISCONNECT

    rasdial
```

So to hang up a vpn named 'The VPN' it'd be:

```
c:\>rasdial "The VPN" /DISCONNECT
```

HTH

Comment: Works great - thanks for your help! I would upvote your answer too, but I don't quite have enough points yet.

Comment: Using it with no entryname appears to disconnect everything; e.g. rasdial /DISCONNECT